# jquery rollover mouse fade image

Tags: jquery

I have jquery script that replace the image when someone rollover wit the mouse on the image.

I want it to be changed with fading.

What do I need to do?

Thanks!

```
<img src='images/dogySitter_s.png' alt='' id='first'  />



<script  type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").hover(
        function() {$(this).attr("src","images/dogySitter_c.png");},
        function() {$(this).attr("src","images/dogySitter_s.png");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `fadeIn()` &  `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

This will fade the element out, swap the images, and fade the element back in (animating the opacity will avoid issues with mouseleave being triggered when the element fades out) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").on({
        mouseenter: function() { 
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 400, function() { 
                $(this).attr('src', 'images/dogySitter_c.png')
                       .animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
            });
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 400, function() { 
                $(this).attr('src', 'images/dogySitter_s.png')
                       .animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

For cross fading you'd need two elements

Comment: @Roi - that's why it says "for cross fading you need two elements", how do you expect to show two images at the same time with one element that just swaps out the source ?

Answer (score 0):

adeneo's answer provides the fadeIn function as a callback of the fadeOut function.  This will work great if you want the image to fade out then have the other one fade back in.

If you want the fading to happen at the same time you will probably have to use some css trickery to place the hidden image over the non-hidden image then call both fadeIn and fadeOut right after each other.  All jQuery animations are execute asynchronously so they will happen at the same time.

More info can be found on fadeOut here http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/